# Change color of geomicons

Tags: css, sass, glyph

I'm using some [`geomicons`](http://jxnblk.com/geomicons-wired/) and need to change their colors.

For example, for `<span class='geomicon-info-alt'/>`, I get a black **circle** with a black letter **i** in it on white background.

[image: original image]

I want to change it to **white** letter **i** on a **black** circle background like this:

[image: expected]

However, if I simply do `color: white; background-color: black`, I'll get a square black background like below.

[image]

Can any one give me some suggestion on how to fix it? 
Thanks,

**Updated**
I tried `border-radius: 50%` as suggested in the comment below. It's much better but there's still a little black in the left edge.

[image]

Comment: can you use `border-radius:50%`

Comment: better check the `geomicon-info-alt` class and customize according to that

Comment: Ahh, I've been trying `radius: 50%` the whole time and wondered why it didn't work :( `border-radius` does do the trick, although there's still little black at the left edge. Do you know how to get rid of it? Also, when you say `check the geomicon-info-alt class`, which source are you referring to? Thanks

Comment: you must use border radius according to your icon height and width

Comment: since you gave the answer first, if you make it as an answer I'll be happy to accept it right away. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying this css you can get the output.

```
.geomicon-info-alt { 
    color:#ffffff;
    background:black;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:0;
}
```

**NOTE :**
If `height` and `width` are same than use `border-radius:50%` otherwise manually change the `border-radius` value to get the desired output..

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following css

```
.geomicon-info-alt { 
    color:#fff;
    background:grey;
    border-radius:50px;
    border:0;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I tried that. pls see my update. Do you know how to get rid of the black/grey in at the very edge?

Comment: I've upvoted your answer but since Amit responded first, I'll wait and see if he'll make his comment as an answer. Thanks